# Disable maven checkstyle, pmd for groovy sources in multimodule project

Tags: java, groovy, maven-3, checkstyle, pmd

I have a multimodule maven project and I can't find a way to disable pmd, checktyle for groovy sources.

I do run a command from the top level:

```
mvn clean install pmd:pmd checktyle:checkstyle
```

The structure of my project is:

```
pom.xml
-module1
 src
   main
      groovy          
   test
      groovy

-module2
 src
   main
      groovy
      java
  test
      groovy
```

I don't want pmd/checkstyle to inspect my groovy files.
Here is parent pom section inside **pluginManagement**:

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <format>xml</format>
        <targetJdk>1.6</targetJdk>
        <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
        <!--
          <excludeRoots>
            <excludeRoot>${project.basedir}/src/main/groovy</excludeRoot>
            <excludeRoot>${project.basedir}/src/test/groovy</excludeRoot>
          </excludeRoots>
        -->
        <!--
        <excludeRoots>
          <excludeRoot>
           ${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/groovy-stubs
          </excludeRoot>
        </excludeRoots>
        -->
        <excludes>
           <exclude>**/generated-sources/groovy-stubs/**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      <rulesets>
       <ruleset>
        ${rule.repository.url}/pmd/rules/pmd-rules/1.0.4.2/pmd-rules-1.0.4.2.xml
       </ruleset>
      </rulesets>
     </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

module1 doesn't have in it's pom.xml any references to pmd/checktyle plugin. Anyway pmd, check style is applied to the groovy sources.

module2 does have reference to these plugins in it's pom.xml And still groovy is not ignored.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Try using includes to say what you want to include, rather than trying to exclude stuff

Comment: If I do specify only "includes" it stops to work at all :)

Answer (score 0):

You can see all directories that have been processed by PMD-plugin if you run Maven with the debug option (-X). All directories are listed in the variable compileSourceRoots.

You can use those excludes for disabling PMD for groovy-stubs:

```
<excludeRoots>
    <excludeRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/groovy-stubs/main</excludeRoot>
    <excludeRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/groovy-stubs/test</excludeRoot>
</excludeRoots>
```